# Drupal 7 nodes slowing website down

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, nodes, content-type

I have a content type in Drupal 7 that consists of 95% of the nodes on my site. I have no use for them now and they have been unpublished.

My question is if those unpublished nodes could be slowing my site down? Would it the site run faster if they were all deleted? I have no use for them at all now but there are over 100000+ pieces of content and I don't know how to delete them except 50 at a time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well yes, they probably can slow down your site. it depends on mysql queries which are you using. if you are really sure you will not need them, than use this module: https://drupal.org/project/delete_all, it will delete nodes by content type "drupal way" = correctly

if you dont want to delete them, you should optimize all of your queries. so try to log slowqueries for a few hours/days and work with them later. this can slow down every page by more than one second if queries are not optimized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily it is slowing down. If there are no views or custom code looking for these nodes, and they are not showing up anywhere, probably they are not causing this problem. In a simple comparison, it's like saying your computer is slow because you have a lot of files in a folder.

But, if you aren't using them and aren't planning to do so, you should probably delete them.

To discover what may be slowing down your site you can use xprof and Drupal Devel module and/or any mysql profiling tool.